# What is object collection in php?

Tags: php, object, collections

I need to create an object with a included collection of objects "tickets". But what is it?

Here is, an object with the embedded object `tickets`:

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [email] => asd@asd.ru
    [phone] => +79243000155
    [tickets] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ticketType] => Adult
            [person] => Array
                (
                    [fullName] => John Doe
                    [FirstName] => John
                )
        )
)
```

But `tickets` must be represented as a **collection of objects**. How it should look like and created?

Answer (score 0):

For PHP, try this:

```
$array = array(
    "email" => "asd@asd.ru",
    "phone" => "+79243000155",
    "tickets" => array(
         "ticketType" => "Adult",
         "person" => array(
             "fullName" => "John Doe",
             "FirstName" => "John"
          )
     )
 );
```

Comment: And what is it? Can you explain it?